# In which sense is $U= C^{1/2} H$ understood for the Cameron Martin space $U$?

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Say we have a normal distribution on an infinite dimensional Hilbert space $H$ with Covariance $C$, which is p.d. such that $C^{1/2}$ exists in some sense. Let $U$ be the Cameron Martin space associated with $C$.
This space has some inner product say $\langle x,y\rangle_U$.

Somewhere I saw someone claim that $U=C^{1/2}H$ without further specifying how this statement is to be understood. I read the introduction in the spde lecture notes on Cameron Martin space on this and the book on stochastic calculus by Karatzas but found no insights there. Can someone provide some reference that explains this in more detail?

I can also add what i would think this means is, namely that
$$ x \in H\Leftrightarrow C^{1/2} x \in U $$ and
$$ \langle x,y\rangle_U = \langle C^{1/2}x, C^{1/2}y\rangle_H = \langle x,Cy\rangle_H$$